# Antiproximanal subspace of $L_1[0,1]$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, banach-spaces

Could someone give a reference or construct an example of closed subspace of $Y\subset L_1[0,1]$ such that $\operatorname{dist}(x,Y)$ is not attained of for any $x\notin Y$.

I read somewhere that $Y$ is necessarily of infinite dimension and codimension.

Comment: The $Y$ in Mikhail's answer has codimension one.  Obviously $Y$ cannot be reflexive, but $Y$ can be of any non zero finite codimension or of infinite codimension. (Let $Z$ be any separable Banach space and let $Q$ be an operator from $L_1$ to $Z$ that maps the closed unit ball of $L_1$ onto the open unit ball of $Z$.  The kernel $Y$ of such a quotient map $Q$ is antiproximinal. It is easy to built such an operator from $\ell_1$ onto $Z$; to get one from $L_1$ compose the operator from $\ell_1$ with a norm one projection from $L_1$ onto a subspace that is isometric to $\ell_1$.)

Comment: @BillJohnson, why don't you post this as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $Y$ in Mikhail's answer has codimension one. Obviously $Y$ cannot be reflexive, but $Y$ can be of any non zero finite codimension or of infinite codimension. (Let $Z$ be any separable Banach space and let $Q$ be an operator from $L_1$ to $Z$ that maps the closed unit ball of $L_1$ onto the open unit ball of $Z$. The kernel $Y$ of such a quotient map $Q$ is antiproximinal. It is easy to built such an operator from $\ell_1$ onto $Z$; to get one from $L_1$ compose the operator from $\ell_1$ with a norm one projection from $L_1$ onto a subspace that is isometric to $\ell_1$.)

Answer (score 6):

Consider any functional $f$ which does not attain its norm on
$L_1[0,1]$ (such $f$ exists by James's theorem, but in this case
one can find it without, as an $L_\infty$-function with essential
supremum equal to $1$, which is not attained on a set of non-zero
measure) and let $Y$ be the kernel of $f$. Let $x\notin Y$, if
$\hbox{dist}(x,Y)$ is attained at $y\in Y$, then $f$ would attain
its norm on $(x-y)/||x-y||$.

Comment: I was always sure that this trick works only for some $x\notin Y$, not  for all of them. Thank you.